# Сurl парсинг ссылки

Tags: php, curl, парсер

Народ помогите не могу парсит [такой запрос](https://s.taobao.com/search?ajax=true&callback=__jsonp_cb&app=imgsearch&tfsid=TB1SZYmLFXXXXatXXXXXXXXXXXX)

вот код:

```
$ch = curl_init('https://s.taobao.com/search?ajax=true&callback=__jsonp_cb&app=imgsearch&tfsid=TB1SZYmLFXXXXatXXXXXXXXXXXX');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'IE20');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$page=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$json = substr($page,35,-3);
$json = json_decode(utf8_encode($json));
print_r($json);
```

Comment: И что подразумеваэться под словом парсить? И что возврашаэт данный скрипт?

Comment: должно возвращает этот: https://s.taobao.com/search?ajax=true&callback=__jsonp_cb&app=imgsearch&tfsid=TB1SZYmLFXXXXatXXXXXXXXXXXX в json

Comment: Должно и возвращает разные вещи. Смотрите ответ ;).

Comment: При чем тут curl и парсить?

Answer (score 2):

Потому что без установленных cookie данный URL возвращает вот это:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
<head><title>302 Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<h1>302 Found</h1>
<p>The requested resource resides temporarily under a different URI.</p>
<hr/>Powered by Tengine</body>
</html>
```

Можете сами удостовериться:

```
curl 'https://s.taobao.com/search?ajax=true&app=imgsearch&tfsid=TB1SZYmLFXXXXatXXXXXXXXXXXX'
```

Comment: Даже с установленный cookie не помогает: `$cookies=tmpfile();
$ch = curl_init('https://s.taobao.com/search?ajax=true&callback=__jsonp_cb&app=imgsearch&tfsid=TB1SZYmLFXXXXatXXXXXXXXXXXX');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'IE20');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookies);//используем куки
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookies);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$page=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$json = substr($page,35,-3);
$json = json_decode(utf8_encode($json));
print_r($json);`

Comment: Конечно, они же пустые у вас.

Comment: Тогда как сохранит и передат cookie?